# Auto Email sending

Tags: php, html, css, email, automation

I have been making a website for a client and he has requested two things. The first is to send an email when a job is assigned to a users accounts and the second is to enable a user to recover a lost password for a the user via an automated email. The website has been coded using HTML5 CSS PHP and SQL for the database back end.

I am unsure of how to set up this function to send this automated email
any help would be greatly appreciated
Thank You

Comment: Do some searching around here, figure out when this email is triggered. AKA at what point in your PHP is this user assigned a job. Create an email function that will use Php and Sql to find that users email in the database and send. The forgot password can be found on Google or here as well

Answer (score 1):

Did you google it?

Use the mail function. http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 1):

Im using phpmailer for that job. :-)

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/

Comment: Why would you need a library?